# Why is this value considered undefined everywhere else in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, mean

I have Books, and Reviews objects.

```
      books: Book[];
  reviews: Review[];
```

The information to fill these arrays are pulled in by a component's functions.

```
  retrieveBooks(): void {
    this.bookService.getAll()
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          this.books = data;
        },
        error => {
          console.log(error);
        }
      );
  }

  retrieveReviews(): void {
    this.reviewService.getAll()
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          this.reviews = data;
        },
        error => {
          console.log(error);
        });
  }
```

The code works, but the array of objects are not recognized.

It says undefined.

Unless I work within the .subscribe ( data => { } )

I could put in a console.log, and the array prints as it should.

But if I try to read the array outside of this function, it will still say undefined.

I don't understand why this is the case, since we've written it to the components arrays we define in the beginning.

Shouldn't this data be accessible throughout the entire component?

Comment: Is you called that function which has return undefined, After getting response from api endpoint?

Comment: they are undefined until you assign some values into them. and the api call subscription takes some time so the variables are `undefined` during the api request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only defined the type. The property has no value assigned, thus it returns `undefined`. You should initialise an empty array beforehand.

```
@Component(){}
export class MyComponent {
  books: Book[] = [];
  reviews: Review[] = [];

  ... more stuff
}
```

*Sidenote: Before you assign the values of books and reviews in `subscribe`, which takes some time, the value is `undefined` ( or in my case `[]`).*